# Can I use custom ethernet shield with standard libraries?

Tags: library, ethernet

I would like to make a custom ethernet card that uses the enc28j60 like this:
[DIY Ethernet card](http://www.picprojects.net/enc28j60_modul/index.html)

but first I would like to know if I can use the standard libraries which can be used with the ethernet card which is in the market like this:
[ENC28J60 ethernet module](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XENC28J60%20module.TRS0&_nkw=ENC28J60%20module&_sacat=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries don't care whether or not you're using a shield, only that you're using a device they support and that you've wired it up how they expect (or that you've modified the library to use the actual wiring you're using). So find a library that supports the ENC28J60 and knock yourself out.